# Simple algebra in a differential equation.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, computer-algebra-systems

I have the differential equation: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin (x-y).$$ Substituting $v=x-y$ and $dy=dx-dv$, I got down to the equation:$$\frac{dv}{1-\sin(v)}=dx.$$
Multiplying the LHS by $\dfrac{1+\sin (v)}{1+\sin(v)}$, I got:$$(\sec^2(v)+\tan (v)\sec (v))dv=dx.$$
This is an easy integral, and I got that $x=\tan(v)+\sec(v)$, with some constant of integration.
Now, doing this in Maple gives the result: $$\frac{2}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}=x,$$
where there should be some constant of integration. Now, I need to use "simple" algebra to show that the equation from Maple leads to: $$x=\frac{1+\tan(\frac{v}{2})}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}+C.$$
How do I show that those two equations are equal? I cannot see the simple algebra that needs to be done.

Comment: Please consider \sin, \cos and \tan to get $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$ instead of $sin$, $cos$ and $tan$.

Comment: Setting $v=0$ leads to $C=1$ and then it follows.

Comment: Fixed the trigonometry. Yes, I know that if C=1 the equation is true. I'm not sure though if I need to have a two distinct constants of integration when going from one to the other. For example the constant of integration on Maple's output might not be the same as C (I'm very sure it isn't). I'm just confused on going from Maple's equation to the new equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
x=\frac{2}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}+C.\tag1
$$
Since $C$ just a constant, then you can manipulate it as follows
$$
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{2}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}+C\\
x&=\frac{2}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}+(K-1)\\
x&=\frac{2}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}-1+K\\
x&=\frac{2-1+\tan(\frac{v}{2})}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}+K\\
x&=\frac{1+\tan(\frac{v}{2})}{1-\tan(\frac{v}{2})}+K.\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: See that's what I was confused on. How the C changes and whether the C in the second one was the C in the first. Thanks :) .

Comment: $$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{G.R.O.O.V.Y.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: @MathMan08 You are welcome. Thank you Ben... **:)**

Answer (score 2):

A more computer-algebra-oriented Answer: To show that two expressions differ by a constant, simplify the derivative of their difference. If you get zero, then they differ by a constant. In Maple, for this problem we get

```
simplify(diff(2/(1-tan(v/2)) - (1+tan(v/2))/(1-tan(v/2)), v));
```

and Maple responds

```
0
```

Comment: Yes, I knew they differed by 1. I just wasn't sure how to show it.